# What is the song called in My hero Academia Season 5 episode 22 at 13:09?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

Reminds me of tekken music i tried to search for it myself but i couldn't find it :)
The songs starts to play at 13:09 in the episode.

I've heard the song before maybe in another anime

Answer (score 1):

found out myself, don't know how to remove question.
song is: Boku no Hero Academia OST Villains Theme

Comment: No need to remove the question, [self-answering is allowed and encouraged](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) :)